# How to suppress specific bar on bar graph in crystal reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

So I am trying to suppress a specific bar on my bar graph. So instead of populating the graph from the database, I am populating it from a formula field. So in my formula field, I have something like this:

```
if field <> "Member" then
formula = field
```

So it gets rid of the field however it leaves me with this:

[image]

I know I can make a subreport that gets rid of that field from the beginning, but I was hoping to avoid creating a subreport for this.

Any ideas? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the help guys, the data will be pretty dynamic..  So I am going to go with the subreport. I will add those little tricks to my toolbox though! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of leaving the group name as blank when the field is "Member", I suggest changing it to be the same as another group which you can always expect to appear on the report - perhaps "SR not handled timely".

This would lump in all the member values with the other group's values, so if you haven't already done so, I suggest graphing the value of a derived field which is set to 0 for "Member". (I suspect you have already done this, as the blank group is showing a value of 0.)

Answer (score 1):

1. The least error-prone method is probably the subreport. If this report is very dynamic, and you always want to hide group A in the graph regardless of it's value, then this is the best way to go.
2. If a static number of groups will be appearing in your graph, you can limit to display the top N groups.  i.e. If there are 7 groups total, and you only want to hide 1 of them (which always has a value of 0), then you can display the Top 6 groups (picture is of Crystal XI):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can set a "specific order" and only include the values you want to include in your graph. In the "Other" tab you need to select "Discard all others".